# node.js - self signed certificate in certificate chain at npm install winax/win32ole package

Tags: node.js, npm-install

When I try to install winax or win32ole package

I get the following error below

I tried:

1. `npm config set strict-ssl false` and
2. `set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` and
3. `npm config set ca ""`

   npm ERR! code 1
   npm ERR! path D:\WebDev\Node\PusherPoll\node_modules\winax
   npm ERR! command failed
   npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
   npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
   npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
   npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | win32 | x64
   npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.6 found at "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe"
   npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.2/node-v16.14.2-headers.tar.gz
   npm ERR! gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack FetchError: request to https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.14.2/node-v16.14.2-headers.tar.gz failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest. (D:\Data\Users\yitzi-zi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:526:28)
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "D:\Data\Users\yitzi-zi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\WebDev\Node\PusherPoll\node_modules\winax
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
   npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok